# .net Dictionary get Key for Value WITHOUT Linq

Tags: .net, dictionary

I can find any number of examples of how to find the key for a given value in a Dictionary using Linq. However, our code has to run cross-platform, and Linq does not work on most of our targets.

So, does anyone have (preferably VB) code that will work with any Dictionary and return `keyForValue`? The "first match" is all we need, as the values will be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it an IDictionary or an IDictionary (generic) one?
For the first, you need to iterate through the stored instances, which are of type DictionaryEntry:

```
foreach (var e in dict.OfType<DictionaryEntry>())
{
    if (e.Value == "target")
    {
    }
}
```

While for generic ones, it is slightly simpler:

```
foreach (var e in dict)
{
    if (e.Value == "target")
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

query in one line:

in C#:

```
string key  = myDict.Keys.ToList()[myDict.Values.ToList().IndexOf(value)]
```

in VB:

```
key =  myDict.Keys.ToList()(myDict.Values.ToList().IndexOf(value))
```

Comment: Not sure if it is guaranteed that the order of items in the two collections is the same.

Comment: It was tested before.

Comment: Tested != guaranteed.

Comment: try to prove the contrary! (or look in the source)

Comment: It can change in future versions. I fully trust that it works right now. Although I grant you that the team is unlikely to change this for fear of breaking code depending un undocumented facts, such as this piece of code.

Comment: I like this solution as it reduces it to one line, and for my data with no duplicates it works fine. Nice solution!

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Module DictionaryHelper
    Public Function KeyForValue(Of TKey, TValue)(dict As Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue), value As TValue) As TKey
        For Each item As KeyValuePair(Of TKey, TValue) In dict
            Dim value2 As TValue = item.Value
            If value2.Equals(value) Then
                Return item.Key
            End If
        Next
        Throw New KeyNotFoundException()
    End Function
End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

Not that experienced in VB, so I answer in C# and hope you can transform it:

```
public TKey GetKeyForValue<TKey,TValue>(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TValue val)
{
    foreach(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> kvp in dictionary)
        if (kvp.Value == val) return kvp.Key;
    return default(TKey); // or throw an appropriate exception for not having found the key
}
```

This iterates through the `KeyValuePair`s in the dictionary and returns the key for the first matching value *without LINQ*.